# SwiftUI : Environment Objects not found during UITest

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to run UI Tests on my Xcode 11 project (to generate snapshots throughout fastlane) but I'm facing a rather odd situation.

When I run the test, the app crashs right after the home page is shown, with the error :

```
Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type TabCommands found. A View.environmentObject(_:) for TabCommands may be missing as an ancestor of this view.: file SwiftUI, line 0
```

**But when running the app normally, I have no such error.**

Here is the hierarchy of the app :

### **Scene Delegate builds the view with environment objects**

```
       let contentView = ContentView()
            .environmentObject(UserManager())
            .environmentObject(TabCommands())
            .environmentObject(IAPStore())


        // Use a UIHostingController as window root view controller.
        if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
            let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
            window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView)
            self.window = window
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
```

### The **content view** uses a TabView based on a UIViewControllerRepresentable:

```
    var body: some View {

        UIKitTabView([
            UIKitTabView.Tab(view: NavigationView {
                HomeContentView()
                    Spacer()
            }, title: "menu_home".localized(), image: "house"),

            UIKitTabView.Tab(view: NavigationView {
                SearchView()
                    Spacer()
            }, title: "menu_home".localized(), image: "magnifyingglass"),

            UIKitTabView.Tab(view: NavigationView {
                UserTabRootLoading()
                    Spacer()
            }, title: "menu_home".localized(), image: "person.crop.circle"),
        ])
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
    }
```

The crash occurs inside the SearchView body, in a navigation link uses an EnvironmentVariable Object for the `isActive` status (in order to pop back 3 Views later without passing the value).

```
struct SearchView: View {

    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>
    @EnvironmentObject var tabCommands: TabCommands
    @EnvironmentObject var userManager: UserManager

    var body: some View {

        ZStack {
            Color.black.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)

            NavigationLink(destination:  PremiumView()
                                             .navigationBarTitle("")
                                             .navigationBarHidden(true),
                            isActive: self.$tabCommands.isStartPremiumViewActive) {
                    EmptyView()
            }.isDetailLink(false)

       }
}
```

(I removed the rest of the code)

The **TabCommand** is an ObservableObject with 6 lines `@Published var myVar = false`
Again, when I run the app on simulator or on device, the app works just as expected, the problems only occurs when I launch UI Tests.

When I try a simple test with just

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
app.launch()
```

the test succeeds. It fails when I add the first line `app.staticTexts["MainButton"].tap()`

Is there some configuration to be done in the Scene Delegate to enable Environment Objects or something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add  .environmentObject(TabCommands()) behind your SearchView....and all other Environmentobjects you are using in there too...not just for ContentView.

like this:

```
  UIKitTabView.Tab(view: NavigationView {
                SearchView().environmentObject(TabCommands())
                    Spacer()
            }, title: "menu_home".localized(), image: "magnifyingglass"),
```

Comment: Ok thanks ! That was a quick fix. Any idea why the environment objects used in the Scene delegate are not made available ?

Comment: they are only made availabe for that view in which you put the envrionmentobject on. exception: if you put the environmentobject to navigationview, all child views will be connected to that envirionmentobject.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the scene delegate. The issue seems to be that the view (`SearchView`) passed in to `UIKitTabView.Tab` doesn't inherit the environment objects from its parent.